# How to get the current active transaction on a Softlayer machine from the Python API?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure, apiconnect

slcli has the option of getting the current active transaction on a machine using `slcli vs detail machine_name | grep active_transaction`. What is the equivalent function on the Python API for Softlayer?

More specifically, I want to find out when the rescue transaction is complete.

`slcli vs detail *** | grep active_transaction
active_transaction  RESCUE_BOOT

slcli vs detail *** | grep active_transaction
active_transaction  CLOUD_ISO_BOOT_TEAR_DOWN

slcli vs detail *** | grep active_transaction
active_transaction  CONFIGURE_CLOUD_NETWORK

slcli vs detail *** | grep active_transaction
active_transaction  NULL`

Is it possible to get the above information through the python API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the following example,

```python
import SoftLayer

USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'

vsiId = 111222333

client = SoftLayer.create_client_from_env(username=USERNAME, api_key=API_KEY)

try:
    active_transaction = client['Virtual_Guest'].getActiveTransaction(id=vsiId)    
    print(active_transaction)
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    pp("Unable to retrieve active transaction: %s, %s " % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
```

The [getActiveTransaction](https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/getActiveTransaction/) returns null when there aren't transactions so it means that it was completed, if you want to check the last transaction use the method [getLastTransaction](https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/getLastTransaction/) instead